# If return a = return b then does a=b?

Tags: haskell, monads, semantics, equality, equational-reasoning

Can you prove that if `return a = return b` then `a=b`? When I use `=`, I mean in the laws and proofs sense, not the `Eq` class sense.

Every monad that I know seems to satisfy this, and I can't think of a valid monad that wouldn't (`Const a` is a functor and applicative, but not a monad.)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

No. Consider the trivial monad:

```
data Trivial a = Cow

instance Monad Trivial where
  _ >>= _ = Cow
  return _ = Cow
```

Comment: ...better known as `Const ()`.

Comment: Why would I pass the opportunity to write `Cow` in a Haskell program?

Comment: Another trivial one is `Cont ()`, whose only proper inhabitant is `cont (\_ -> ())` or however that's spelled.

Comment: What about non-trivial monads?

Comment: @dfeuer: Parametricity plus the need to comply with the monad laws can be used rule out the middle ground, the trivial monad is the only case where this is violated, everything else needs to call the function passed to `(>>=)` with a valid `a` -- or it'll fails the first monad law. -- `Cont ()` is the trivial monad up to isomorphism -- The proof of both of these observations is left to you as an exercise. ;)

There is a dual argument available in the comonad case, if `w a = w b` structurally then either `w` is the uninhabited comonad or `a = b`.

Comment: @EdwardKMETT, any monad with just one element (up to bottoms) is trivial, of course. `Cont` has nasty things like `_|_` vs. `const _|_`. Ah yes, I started thinking about `f >=> return` and somehow got stuck on that without considering the far more relevant `return >=> f`.

Comment: Note: `Cont Void` and `Cont ()` both work but for subtly different reasons.

Comment: @EdwardKMETT, `return` produces sensible inhabitants of `Cont Void a` for any inhabited `a`, but none of them can be distinguished from each other because none of them can ever be applied to a sensible function. Right? This is just `a -> not (not a)`, while `Cont ()` gets the less exciting `a -> True`.

Comment: @dfeuer Depends. Do you consider `absurd` to be sensible?

Comment: `absurd` is sensible, even classically. It is simply the logical principle of ex falso quodlibet, or that you can build a function from the empty set, by enumerating where it sends all inhabitants of the set. 

The existence of `undefined :: Void` is the degenerate part.

Comment: @EdwardKMETT: you're using special properties of Haskell here. There are plenty of monads in mathematics whose unit is not injective.

Comment: Absolutely. That was more or less implied by the question using `return` and my reply exploiting parametricity. =)

Comment: Is that a cow-monad?